# Failed to create a project in an application using j meter

Tags: jmeter

I need to create a project in a application using j meter but in HTTP request parameter contains "created on(date & time)" If I give the details and compiled the testplan no error is shown but project is not created. How can I give time stamps for multiple projects created by multiple users simultaneously.Is there any listener to get time stamps automatically.

Comment: Do you need to pass in random timestamps per HTTP request?  Or is this coming from a list you have?

Comment: Problem is solved i had given the wrong parameter in the name field

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [__time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function to generate timestamp in arbitrary format controllable via [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.

For more information on this and other JMeter functions see [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series.